# shortpath. distance-calculation. java.

Tags: java, distance

help please. i am trying to write a program to calculate distances between stations. I want to get an input from users where they are and where they want to go. this is what i have so far. i am stuck. what do i do next?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StationDist {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] stations = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
        //Set up the stations array of doubles here

        double[][] distances = new double[stations.length][];
        for(int i=0; i < stations.length; i++) {
            distances[i] = new double[i+1];
            for(int j=0; j<distances[i].length; j++) {
                distances[i][j] = Math.abs(stations[i] - stations[j]);
            }
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(distances[i]));
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the destnation: ");
        System.out.println("1 for london.");
        System.out.println("2 for bristol");
        System.out.println("3 for oxford");
        System.out.println("4 for warwick");
        KeyboardInput in = new KeyboardInput();
        int val = in.readInteger();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(distances[val]));
    }

}
```

Comment: So the distances are straight lines? I'm a little confused, since I would think you would want a graph structure in order to use, for example, Dijkstra's algorithm, but I'm not sure what the context of your homework assignment is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your input here - from your stations array it looks like everything is in a straight line. However, to do distance algorithms you'll want to use something like Djikstra's algorithm (which calculates the shortest distance from one node to all other nodes). For more information and some pseudo-code, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djikstra%27s_algorithm